# Can I make tmux scroll from my trackpad?

Tags: iterm, tmux

I want to set up iTerm2 to pass scroll events to tmux, so I can trivially enter (and exit) scrollback mode for whatever pane is active. Is this possible to do with iTerm2, or automation of some sort, or ...?

Comment: For`tmux` version 2.1 or higher follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185210/ubuntu-change-tmux-1-8-to-tmux-next-1-9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mode is referred to as "copy mode" and as long as you're running `tmux` 1.5 or higher you can add:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

to your `~/.tmux.conf` file and tmux will automatically enter and exit copy mode when you use the scroll wheel on your mouse.

As a bonus, this option allows you to select the tmux pane with your mouse:

```
set -g mouse-select-pane on
```

Answer (score 7):

As seen in this related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-doesnt-work

The command to enable scrolling & easy copy to clipboard highlighting is the following:

```
set -g mouse on
```